# Lemma as a type in a record

Tags: coq

Beginner here! 
How do we I interpret a record that looks something like this?

```
 Record test A B :=
{
  CA: forall m, A m; 
  CB: forall a b m, CA m ==> B(a,b);
}
```

I am trying to get a sense of what an instance of this record would look like and moreover, what it means to have a quantified lemma as a type.

Comment: What are the types of `A` and `B`?

Comment: I am assuming A is a unary predicate and B a binary predicate. Would the meaning of this record be different depending on what actual types I assign to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are writing cannot make sense because the notation `_ ==> _` is supposed to link two boolean values.  But `CA` has type `A m`, which is itself a type, not a boolean value.

One possibility to go forward would be to make `CA` a boolean function that could represent the `A` predicate.

Another difficulty with your hypothetical record is that we don't know what are the input types for `A` and `B`, so I will assume we live in an ambient type `T` over which quantifications appear.  So here is a variant:

```
Record test (T : Type) (A : T -> Prop) (B : T * T -> bool) :=
{
  CA : T -> bool;
  CA_A : forall m, CA m = true -> A m;
  CB : forall a b m, (CA m ==> B(a, b)) = true
}.
```

This example forces you to understand that there are two distinct concepts in this logical language: `bool` values and `Prop` values.  They represent different things, which can sometimes be amalgamated but you need to make the distinction clear in your head to leave the category of *beginner*.

For your last sentence "what it means to have a quantified lemma as a type" here is another explanation.

When programming with a conventional programming language, you can return arrays of integers.  However, you cannot be explicit and say that you want to return an array of integers of a *specific length*.  In Gallina (the basic programming language of Coq), you can define a type of arrays of length 10.  Let us assume that such a type would be written `array n`.  So `array 10` and `array 11` would be two different types.  A function that takes as input a number `n` and return as output an array of length `n` would have the following type:

`forall n, array n`

So an object that has a quantified formula as a type simply is a function.

From a logical point of view, the statement `forall n, array n` is usually read as *for every `n` there exists an array of `size n`*.  This statement is probably no surprise to you.

So the type of an array depends on an indice.  Now we can think of another type, for example, the *type of proofs that `n` is prime*.  Let's assume this type is written `prime n`.  Surely, there are numbers that are not prime, so for example the type `prime 4` should not contain any proof at all.  Now I may write a function called `test_prime : nat -> bool` with the property that when it returns `true` I have the guarantee that the input is prime.  This would be written as such:

```
forall n, test_prime n = true -> prime n
```

Now, if I want to define a collection of all correct prime testing functions, I would want to associate in one piece of data the function and the proof that it is correct, so I would define the following data type.

```
Record certified_prime_test :=
  {
     test_prime : nat -> bool;
     certificate : forall n, test_prime n = true -> prime nat
  }.
```

So records that contain universally quantified formulas can be in one of these two categories: either one component is one of this function whose output varies across several types of the same family (like in the example of `array`) or one of the components actually brings more logical information about another component which is a function.  In the `certified_prime_test` example, the `certificate` component brings more information about the `test_prime` function.

Comment: That clears up a lot of my confusion. I was trying to recreate a record I saw in my test example. Ended up replacing -> with ==> and also the confusion with bools and props. Thank you for this thorough explanation.

Comment: @Yves There is a small typo that makes the first paragraph about primes rather unreadable (a confusion between `*` and `\``). Could you please correct it?